# Understanding of the yield function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am analyzing the following code sample:

```
>>> def check(v):
...     for t in v:
...             yield t
...             if t==2:
...                     yield "a"
```

Do I understand correctly that the two last lines of code will never be executed, because `yield` works as `return`. So, basically the first `yield` in a for loop (before the if clause) will always be applied.

Is my understanding correct?

**UPDATE:**

I do not understand why do I get the sequence 2, a, 2, a, 1, ... and not this one: 1,a,1,...

```
>>> my_list = [2,2,1,2,3]
>>> f = check(my_list)
>>> f.next()
2
>>> f.next()
'a'
>>> f.next()
2
>>> f.next()
'a'
>>> f.next()
1
>>> f.next()
2
```

Comment: This is called generators. Shameless plug: read my [blog post](http://rahmonov.me/posts/python-generators/) about them :)

Comment: *"`yield` works as `return`"* - No, `return` works as `return`. There's no reason to have two different `return` by two different names. Why would the second one make more sense; it's a "`return`" in a loop, which would also be rather pointless.

Comment: No, `yield` is not the same as `return`

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov: I read your post, thanks. I understand the difference between `yield` and `return`. However, what I do not understand is if the `if` will ever be executed in my first code sample.

Comment: I will try to explain generators with an example using the same algorithm: try in console: `>>>f = check("some value")` them to get yield one by one you can run: `>>>f.__next__()`

Comment: Yes it will. And @DanielHeidemann that is incorrect. calling `check` again *creates a new generator*. You mean calling `next(gen_object)` on the generator object *returned by `check`*

Comment: In short: yes, the `if` *will* be executed (*if* something is reading from the generator…).

Comment: @Dinosaurius Upd: sorry, I am mistaken. Yes, it will be execured

Comment: @DanielHeidemann: So, do you want to say that the first `yield` will be executed when the function `check` is called the first time, and then in the next calls `if` will be executed? Could you put some relevant example?

Comment: @Dinosaurius that's the beauty of `generators`, it will give you the control back after `yielding` and then will continue where it left off

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for pointing it out. I was a bit unclear. I was thinking of for c in check(). I have removed the comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Manu: I get the error `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__next__'`.

Comment: @Dinosaurius because you are on Python 2, so the method is `.next`. Do yourself a favor, get on Python 3. But in either case, use the built-in function `next` not the method directly

Comment: So, I appreciate if someone could post the step-by-step explanation of my example. I am still very confused and my tests from command line did not help me better understand `yield` for my particular case.

Comment: @Dinosaurius go read about generators. Read the posted duplicate, which is one of the most up-voted questions on stack overflow. Use Python 3, and make sure you are reading about Python 3, since the iterator protocol changed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I switched to Python 3. I do not understand why I get 2, a,2,a,1,2,a,3 for my posted example. I understand the first value, but the second one is meaningless. And yes, I read the post that you referenced.

Comment: Because you yield the number you are iterating over, then if the number is equal to `2`, you yield `'a'`... what don't you understand?

Comment: @Dinosaurius in python 2 you need first write at the begining of code `from __future__ import generators` let me know how it was?